# Map unhanded requests to html page in .net webAPI application

Tags: c#, .net, routes, webapi

I'm trying to map any request that doesn't start with `api/` to return a static html file.
Here is the mapping I already have:

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiWithId",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            null,
            new { id = @"\d.+" });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiWithAction",
            "api/{controller}/{action}");
        ...
        // controller injector
    }
}
```

Ideally I would prefer to have something like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "NotAPI",
    "^(?!api\/).*",
    "~/index.html"
    );
```

So far I've only managed to make the application return a specific action when none of the other routes get matched, using the following code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "NotAPI",
    "{*url}",
    new { Controller = "Test", Action = "Test" } // currently just returning `Ok("Hello World")`
    );
```

Is there a way to directly map the request to the file or do I have to read the file and return its contents?